# Get value from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

it asks the user to enter a class name. but prints not found

```
myDict={"John":["Maths261,"Econ120"],"Mathew":["CSIS256,"Econ120"]}
    classFind=input("Enter Name to find class:")
    for key in myDict:
        if classFind in key:
            tmpVal=myDict[key]
            print(tmpVal)

        else:
            print("Not found")
```

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are searching names as opposed to classes, you could replace the `for` loop with

```
tmpVal = myDict.get(classFind, "Not found")
print(tmpVal)
```

which I believe follows the hint in the comment to your question.

So if the value of `classFind` is a key in your dictionary, its value will be printed. Otherwise it will print `"Not found"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
myDict = {"John":["Maths261","Econ120"],"Mathew":["CSIS256","Econ120"]} 

classFind = raw_input("Enter Name to find class:") 

if classFind in myDict.keys() :
    print myDict[classFind]

else :
    print "Not Found"
```

If you enter someone's name you will be returned their courses.

Comment: It gets the value but still prints not found

Answer (score 0):

```
myDict={"John":["Maths261","Econ120"],"Mathew":["CSIS256","Econ120"]}
classfind = raw_input('enter classname : ')
for name, classes in myDict.iteritems():
    if classfind in classes:
        print name
```

output:

```
enter classname : Econ120
Mathew
John
```